# DDD, how and where to add db Table unrealated to domain?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Trying to build a stample project using DDD, I'm facing an issue:
 To validate zipcode, address, and etc.., I have a set of db table(20 tables hundreds of columns, 26Mo) that I would like to query.
 Those table are not related to my domain. This table have their own connection string and can be stored outside of the persitance DB.

I was thinking of adding a connection string to the Core and use a simple orm raw sql query to validate the data.
 The process is easyer to write in C# than in SQL so there is no stored procedure to do the job.

There is no modification on those data. Only querying.

Comment: Factual information on Tables structure were add to clarify that addmin them to domain will be a major flood. Even if EF can auto generate the table and configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's important to remember that DDD doesn't have to apply to *everything* you do. If you have a complex problem domain that is worthy of the complexities DDD brings, that's fine. However it's also fine to have other areas of your software (other boundaries, essentially) that are CRUD. In fact, CRUD is best where you can get away with it because of the simplicity. As @D.R. said, you can load data using something more akin to a Transaction Script (I can see something like IZipCodeValidator in your future) and pass the results of that in where you need them, or you might consider your Application Service being allowed to go and get that ZipCode data using CRUD (IZipCodeRepository) and passing that in to a full-on Domain Object that has complex rules for the validation.

I believe it's a DDD purist view to try and avoid passing things to methods on Domain Objects that do things (e.g. `DomainObject.ValidateAddress(address, IZipCodeRepository repo)`), instead preferring to pass in the values useful for the validation (e.g. `DomainObject.ValidateAddress(address, IEnumerable<ZipCode> zipcodes)`). I think anyone could see the potential for performance issues there, so your mileage may vary. I'll just say to *resist* it if you can.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bounded context of its own. I'd probably query it from the core domain using an anti-corruption layer in-between. So your domain simply uses an interface to a service. Your application layer would implement this interface with the anti-corruption layer to the other bounded context. The implementation can use simple DB query mechanisms like ADO.NET queries.